# Why is $x = c$ an inflection point only if the lowest-order (above the second) non-zero derivative is of odd order (third, fifth, etc.).

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So according to wikipedia [inflection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point),

> If the second derivative, $f''(x)$ exists at $x_0$, and $x_0$ is an inflection point for $f$, then $f''(x_0) = 0$, but this condition is not sufficient for having a point of inflection, even if derivatives of any order exist. In this case, one also needs the lowest-order (above the second) non-zero derivative to be of odd order (third, fifth, etc.). If the lowest-order non-zero derivative is of even order, the point is not a point of inflection, but an undulation point.

It is also mentioned that:

> the condition that the first nonzero derivative has an odd order implies that the sign of $f'(x)$ is the same on either side of $x$ in a neighborhood of $x$

My question is why is it the case? For example, if $f^{3}(c)$ is nonzero, while $f''(c) = 0$.  How does the first condition contribute to the fact that $(x, f(x))$ is not an undulation point?.  I found this non-obvious but I couldn't find any explanation online. So I am seeking a proof (or any kind of intuition) for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about the Taylor polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the Taylor development, assuming WLOG the inflection point at $x=0$, we have

$$f(x)\approx f(0)+f'(0)x+f^{(n)}(0)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

where $n$ is the order of the first nonzero derivative ($n>1$). For $x$ small enough, the higher order terms have no influence. To get an inflection, the last term must be an odd function, so that the curve can cross the straight line $y=f(0)+f'(0)x$.

Below, plots of $1-x, 1-x+x^2,1-x+x^3,1-x+x^4,1-x+x^5$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f$ is $C^\infty$ in a neighborhood of $x=0$. Then the  the tangent to the graph of $f$ at $x=0$ is given by $y=t(x):=f(0)+f'(0) x$.
We now have to study the function $g(x):=f(x)-t(x)$ in the neighborhood of $x=0$. In any case $g(0)=g'(0)=0$.  When all derivative values $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ $\>(n\geq2)$ these derivative values cannot tell us anything about the behavior of $g$ near $x=0$, since $g$ has all derivatives $=0$ at $x=0$.

Now let us assume that there is some $n\geq2$ with
$$f^{(k)}(0)=0\quad (2\leq k<n),\qquad f^{(n)}(0)=:c\ne 0\ .$$
Then Taylor's theorem tells us that
$$g(x)=c{x^n\over n!}+o(x^n)=x^n\left({c\over n!}+o(1)\right)\qquad(x\to0)\ .$$
This says that $g(x)$ is of a single sign in a punctured neighborhood of $x=0$, when $n$ is even, and $g$ (having the $x$-axis as tangent at $x=0$) changes sign when $x$ passes through $0$, when $n$ is odd. The latter behavior you would describe as an *inflection point* of $f$ at $x=0$.